# Is it possible to compile boost::recursive_mutex statically in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, boost, c++builder, boost-thread, c++builder-2010

`boost::recursive_mutex` and `boost::lock_guard` seem to use **boost_thread-bcb-mt-1_39.dll** in C++ Builder 2010. I see that there is also static version - **boost_thread-bcb-mt-1_39.lib**.

My code is something like this:

```
boost::recursive_mutex mylock;
//...
boost::lock_guard<boost::recursive_mutex> lock(mylock);
```

However, if I set compile option to **Release** and set Dynamic RTL option to **False** all I get is **Mixing a dll boost library with a static runtime is a really bad idea...**. Returning Dynamic RTL to **True** compiles but then it needs additional DLL's - **cc32100mt.dll** and **boost_thread-bcb-mt-1_39.dll**.

Is there a way to compile it statically in a single exe? After all, LIB file is provided, it should be possible. Is it a problem with this version of C++ Builder or Boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I needed was to define in a header file:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB
```

right before:

```
#include <boost/thread/recursive_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
```

After then it compiles without any issues.